# Scikit-learn, Numpy: Changing the value of an read-only variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm currently using `scikit-learn` to train a [SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html).

After I train a model on my data, I want to change `coef_` of my model.

```
#initiate svm
model = svm.SVC(Parameters...)

#train the model with data
model.fit(X,y)

#Now i want to change the coef_ attribute(A numpy array)
model.coef_ = newcoef
```

Problem: It gives me an `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. Or when I try to access the numpy array in the attribute it gives me
`ValueError: assignment destination is read-only`.

Is there a way to change the attributes of the existing model?

(I want to do this because I want to parallelize the SVM training,
and have to change the `coef_` attribute for this.)

Comment: Hi @user3811872 if this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SVM doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html):

> coef_ is a readonly property derived from dual_coef_ and
>   support_vectors_

And from the implementation of `model.coef_`:

```
@property
def coef_(self):
    if self.kernel != 'linear':
        raise AttributeError('coef_ is only available when using a '
                             'linear kernel')

    coef = self._get_coef()

    # coef_ being a read-only property, it's better to mark the value as
    # immutable to avoid hiding potential bugs for the unsuspecting user.
    if sp.issparse(coef):
        # sparse matrix do not have global flags
        coef.data.flags.writeable = False
    else:
        # regular dense array
        coef.flags.writeable = False
    return coef

def _get_coef(self):
    return safe_sparse_dot(self._dual_coef_, self.support_vectors_)
```

You can see that `model.coef_` is a `property`, and its value is calculated every time when you access it.

So one cannot assign a value to it. Instead, one can change the values of `model.dual_coef_` and `model.support_vectors_`, so that `model.coef_` will then be updated.

Following is an example:

```
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(model.coef_)
#[[ 0.          0.59479519 -0.96654219 -0.44609639]
#[ 0.04016065  0.16064259 -0.56224908 -0.24096389]
#[ 0.7688616   1.11070473 -2.13349078 -1.88291061]]

model.dual_coef_[0] = 0
model.support_vectors_[0] = 0

print(model.coef_)
#[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
#[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
#[ 0.7688616   1.11070473 -2.13349078 -1.88291061]]
```

Comment: Hi @user3811872 if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.